# Flexslider not working on auto generated content with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flexslider

I have a text area which contains the post content, I want to make a slider with the Flexslider Jquery plugin when the post has more than image but unfortunately the plugin not working.

HTML CODE

```
<textarea id='summary7731158085902631382' style='display:none;'>
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;">

<a href="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-tqkOgHfEp10/VKHDxv709UI/AAAAAAAABKo/IA6lz5cdGfE/s1600/unsplash_1.jpg">
<img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-tqkOgHfEp10/VKHDxv709UI/AAAAAAAABKo/IA6lz5cdGfE/s1600/unsplash_1.jpg" />
</a>

<a href="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-88jaynpnczQ/VKHDxr9NHXI/AAAAAAAABKs/PusKWOwGCYw/s1600/unsplash_2.jpg">
<img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-88jaynpnczQ/VKHDxr9NHXI/AAAAAAAABKs/PusKWOwGCYw/s1600/unsplash_2.jpg" />
</a>

<a href="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-JY0gtfw46YY/VKHDxgz63KI/AAAAAAAABK0/r0mvJkP_FE0/s1600/unsplash_3.jpg">
<img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-JY0gtfw46YY/VKHDxgz63KI/AAAAAAAABK0/r0mvJkP_FE0/s1600/unsplash_3.jpg" /></a>

<br />

<p>Cras sit amet libero eros, in ultricies lorem. Nunc et odio neque.   Maecenas vehicula interdum hendrerit. Integer hendrerit orci ullamcorper neque pellentesque feugiat. Aliquam magna metus, fringilla non ultrices id, fringilla eu erat. Phasellus lorem tortor, porttitor volutpat iaculis sed, condimentum ultricies massa. Curabitur ut malesuada elit. Nullam tortor mi, faucibus a laoreet a, ultricies ut est. Etiam erat urna, dapibus vitae sodales eu, sagittis ut nisl. Curabitur vitae tristique felis. Donec consectetur porttitor lectus ac pharetra. Mauris nulla nisi, congue quis eleifend at, dapibus eget augue. Curabitur nunc sem, feugiat sit amet facilisis quis, laoreet id mi.
</p>
</div>
</textarea>
<div id='content'></div>
```

Jquery CODE

```
var sum = '',
  content = $('#summary7731158085902631382').val(),
  imgs = $(content).find('img');

if (imgs.length > 1) {
  sum = '<div class="flexslider"><ul>';
  for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    var img = imgs[i].src;
    sum += '<li><a href="' + img + '"><img alt="" src="' + img + '"></a></li>';
  }
  sum += '</ul></div>';
}
$('#content').html(sum);
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
  animation: "slide",
  controlNav: false,
  smoothHeight: true,
  prevText: "",
  nextText: ""
});
```

[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k10z7z06/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add one class to ul tag, i.e. "slide" : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k10z7z06/2/)

```
sum = '<div class="flexslider"><ul class="slides">';
```